# how to print an integer (of another function) from main function?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return-value

I have just begin learning java. Could any one tell me how to print int c from main function?

Here's my code:

```
class code {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    sum(44.1, 55.6);
    product(34.1, 1.1);
    System.out.print(c);
  }

  public static double sum(double a, double b) {
    double c=a+b;
    return c;
  }

  public static void product(double a, double b) {
    double c=a*b;
    System.out.print(c);
  }
}
```

Why c is not coming in main function?

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\BN Com\Documents\JCreator Pro\MyProjects\square    
System.out.print(c);    
                 ^  
symbol: variable c  
location: class code    
1 error
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please post your actual code, not a link to it.

Comment: You want to access local variable defined in method. It's impossible. Did you read any basic books about Java before?

Comment: Try to learn *Variable Scope*; Hope you can solve it then :)

Comment: OK! Thanks to all! now I have understand.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't declare the variable c in main function. try this

System.out.print(sum(44.1,55.6));

Answer (score 2):

`c` is a local variable in `sum`. You cannot refer to it outside this method. You could, however, store the returned value in a local variable in `main` and use it from there. E.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int s = sum(44.1, 55.6);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand the meaning of variable [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html). In this case, your variable `c` is declared only inside your `sum` function. You are not able to access it outside that function. Same goes for `c` in the `product` function. If you wish to print the value, you have two options.

The first one, printing from inside the function, as you did with `product`. Then, when you call that function in `main`, the value will be printed.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    product(1,2); //This will print the value
}
```

Second one, return the value as you did with `sum`, but assign it to a variable on `main` and then print it. You may also call the function inside `System.out.prinln()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Print directly
    System.out.println(sum(1,2));

    //Assign to a variable and print. Note that this c is no the same
    //variable you have inside your functions.
    double c= sum(1,2);
    System.out.println(c);
}
```